# Ubuntu erased my Windows when I chose to replace old Ubuntu install

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, data-recovery, partitioning

I was installing Ubuntu 13.10 and chose to replace the old Ubuntu 12.04. The problem is that the new installation also erased my Windows and installed the new Ubuntu using all space available in my HD, instead of keeping the dual boot.

That also happened with my friend, we are both developers that need both OS. Very sad, this should be fixed.

EDIT:

As @oldfred said: "Reinstall says overwrite Ubuntu but it also erases existing Windows. [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/126519](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192)2"

Comment: If it overwrote the entire disk, that was an option that you chose during the install and is unrecoverable, if it simply doesn't let you *boot* into windows (but the files are still there) then you may be able to recover it through some bootloader repairs

Comment: I did not chose that. I just chose to replace the current Ubuntu install for the new one. I checked and it overwrote the entire disk. If this is the default option it needs to be changed.

Comment: Reinstall says overwrite Ubuntu but it also erases existing Windows.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192  If it is just a description, it usually is not a bug as software is doing exactly what the programer planned. But poor or not clear instructions are a major issue.

Comment: @bain This is another case. In your provided question the user tried to overwrite Vista with Ubuntu. In my case I tried to overwrite Ubuntu with Ubuntu and keep my dual boot with Windows. I don't want to recover anything, thanks God I had backups. I just want to change this dark default behavior, like the comment above yours says: "Reinstall says overwrite Ubuntu but it also erases existing Windows."

Comment: AskUbuntu is the place for user support questions and answers. Problems or bugs with Ubuntu itself should be communicated to the responsible developers on Launchpad. If you get no appropriate response there, then try the ubuntu-devel and ubuntu-devel-discuss mailing lists.